# Can't print the sum of two integers in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x

I have the following code for Python training:

```
import sys
# Declare second integer, double, and String variables.
i=12
d=4.0
s="HackerRank"

# Read and save an integer, double, and String to your variables.
x=input("enter integer x:")
y=input("enter double y:")
z=input("enter string z:")
# Print the sum of both integer variables on a new line.
print(i+x)
# Print the sum of the double variables on a new line.
print(y+d)
# Concatenate and print the String variables on a new line
print(s+z)
# The 's' variable above should be printed first.
```

What I want to achieve is the following:

> Print the sum of *i* plus your int variable on a new line. Print the sum
>   of *d* plus your double variable to a scale of one decimal place on a
>   new line. Concatenate *s* with the string you read as input and print
>   the result on a new line.

When I run my code, I got this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:...\lesson2.py", line
>   12, in 
>       print(i+x) TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Can you help please?

**EDIT:**
I read all the comment. I get error when adding two double types. I tried double casting but it does not work:

```
import sys
# Declare second integer, double, and String variables.
i=12
d=4.0
s="HackerRank"

# Read and save an integer, double, and String to your variables.
x=input("enter integer x:")
y=input("enter double y:")
z=input("enter string z:")
# Print the sum of both integer variables on a new line.
print(i+int(x))
# Print the sum of the double variables on a new line.
print(y+double(d))
# Concatenate and print the String variables on a new line
print(s+z)
# The 's' variable above should be printed first.
```

The error is:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:...\lesson2.py", line
>   14, in 
>       print(y+double(d)) NameError: name 'double' is not defined

Comment: Convert your variables x, y and z to ints by doing int(x) etc.

Comment: The error explains the issue. Can't add an int and str together. So you should thing how to make your string an integer to use.

Comment: Homework problem....

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you should be aware of type conversions in python.

When you write `x=input("enter integer x:")`, it will take input in `string` format.

So

```
  print(i+x)
```

implies, add an integer value stored in `i` and string value stored in `x`. This operation is not supported in python.

So you should use either of the following

```
 x = int(input("enter integer x:"))
```

or

```
 print(i + int(x))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# Read and save an integer, double, and String to your variables.
x=int(input("enter integer x:"))
y=float(input("enter double y:"))
z=str(input("enter string z:"))
# Print the sum of both integer variables on a new line.
print(i+int(x))
# Print the sum of the double variables on a new line.
print(y+(d*2))
# Concatenate and print the String variables on a new line
print(str(s)+": " + str(z))
# The 's' variable above should be printed first.
```

that is how i prefer to do my homework.

Answer (score 0):

`input(...)` gives you a string in python 3.x in python 2.x the behaviour was different. If you want to read an int you have to explicitly convert it using `int(input(...))`.

Answer (score 0):

My solution un python 3 is :

```
   numero1 =int(0)
numero2 =float(0.0)
texto = ""  



# Read and save an integer, double, and String to your variables.
numero1 = int(input())

numero2 = float(input())

texto = input()

# Print the sum of both integer variables on a new line.
c_int_sum = int(numero1+i)
print (c_int_sum)

# Print the sum of the double variables on a new line.
c_float_sum = float(numero2+d) 
Rnf = round(c_float_sum,1);
print (Rnf)
# Concatenate and print the String variables on a new line
print (s+texto)
```