# Python - ValueError: could not convert string to float: '52.04121.43433.681035'

Tags: python, string, floating-point

Here is my code (it is kind of long and could probably be simplified)

```
hours = float(input("Enter the number of hours worked in a week:"))
dep = float(input("Enter the number of dependents you have:"))

rate = 16.68
ovrate = 25.02


if hours<=40:
  gross = "{:.2f}".format(float(hours * rate))
else:
  gross = "{:.2f}".format(float((40*rate)+((hours-40)*ovrate)))
gross2 = float(gross)
print("Gross pay: $",gross)

ss = "{:.2f}".format(gross2*.06)
print("Social Security tax: $",ss)

federal = "{:.2f}".format(gross2*0.14)
print("Federal income tax: $",federal)

state = "{:.2f}".format(gross2*0.5)
print("State income tax: $",state)

union=10
print("Union dues: $10.00")
unionString=str(union)

if dep>=3:
  family = 35
  print("Family health insurance: $35.00 (additional insurance premiums for your family)")
else:
  family = 0
familyString = str(family)

netDed = ss+federal+state+unionString+familyString
netDedFloat = float(netDed)
netDed2 = "{:.2f}".format(netDedFloat)
print("Total deductions: $",netDed2)

netPay = gross2-netDed
print("Net pay: $",netPay)
```

When I run it, I get the following message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 39, in <module>
    netDedFloat = float(netDed)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '52.04121.43433.681035'
```

I have tried everything I have read online. I get a different error every time. Please help me understand this error and how to solve it.

Edit:
'52.04121.43433.681035' is because I entered 48 for hours and 4 for dependents. This number varies depending on the inputs. This is the complete output for this scenario.

```
Enter the number of hours worked in a week:48
Enter the number of dependents you have:4
Gross pay: $ 867.36
Social Security tax: $ 52.04
Federal income tax: $ 121.43
State income tax: $ 433.68
Union dues: $10.00
Family health insurance: $35.00 (additional insurance premiums for your family)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 39, in <module>
    netDedFloat = float(netDed)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '52.04121.43433.681035'
```

I am a beginner, so please forgive me if I ask you to elaborate.

Comment: That is a large part of my confusion. I am trying to add the values together and the error message is showing me all of the values put together into one number

Comment: Right, none of the objects you're working with are numbers.

Comment: If you are attempting to evaluate *arithmetic addition*, you need to convert each of `ss`, `federal`, `state`, `union`, and `family` to float values and *then* add them.

Comment: The `+` operator is string concatenation, and your values are strings -- e.g., `"a" + "b"` is `"ab"`.

Comment: check my edit to the post, it elaborates a bit!

Comment: Converting them all is one of the things I tried. It showed a different error message.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't print the sum of two integers in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39039058/cant-print-the-sum-of-two-integers-in-python-3)

Comment: Then you simply did it incorrectly. Please show that attempt and the error message you got. The string formatting `"{:.2f}".format(gross2*0.5)` does *not* turn the value into a float, it's just string formatting.

Comment: What I did before was add float to the right side of the statement. Ex: federal = float("{:.2f}".format(gross2*0.14))

Comment: Please read the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) as you have a fundamental misunderstanding of the different data types.

Comment: I'll look it over again. I'm sorry if I sound like a complete imbecile

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your code gives an error because in this line

`netDed = ss+federal+state+unionString+familyString` every variable is a string and you try to add string to string.`('123.0'+'12'='123.012')`

You need to convert these values to `float`.I am comment where I change the code.

```py
hours = float(input("Enter the number of hours worked in a week:"))
dep = float(input("Enter the number of dependents you have:"))

rate = 16.68
ovrate = 25.02


if hours<=40:
  gross = "{:.2f}".format(float(hours * rate))
else:
  gross = "{:.2f}".format(float((40*rate)+((hours-40)*ovrate)))
gross2 = float(gross)
print("Gross pay: $",gross)

ss = float("{:.2f}".format(gross2*.06)) # Converting in to float
print("Social Security tax: $",ss)

federal = float("{:.2f}".format(gross2*0.14)) # Converting in to float
print("Federal income tax: $",federal)

state = float("{:.2f}".format(gross2*0.5)) # Converting in to float
print("State income tax: $",state)

union=10
print("Union dues: $10.00")
unionString=float(union) # Converting in to float

if dep>=3:
  family = 35
  print("Family health insurance: $35.00 (additional insurance premiums for your family)")
else:
  family = 0
familyString = float(family) # Converting in to float

netDed = ss+federal+state+unionString+familyString

netDedFloat = float(netDed)
netDed2 = "{:.2f}".format(netDedFloat)
print("Total deductions: $",netDed2)

netPay = gross2-netDed
print("Net pay: $",netPay)
```

Comment: OK, but all you've done is echoed their code.  You haven't told them how to fix it.

Comment: Well, sort of.  There's no point in converting those values to string and then back to float.  Values like `2.60` will print as `2.6`.

Comment: So, strings cannot be added?

Comment: You can add strings, but what that does is concatenate them.  It does not do a mathematical operation.  `"12"+"34"+"56"` produces `"123456"`.

Comment: For what it's worth, that operation DOES work in PHP (`"12"+"34"+"56"` produces `"102"`), but Python is more strongly typed than PHP.

Answer (score -1):

The problem here is that `ss`, `federal`, `state`, `unionString` and `familyString` are all strings.  When you add strings, you concatenate them, you don't add their numerical values.

What you need to do is keep those things as floats.  You can use `format` when you print them, but don't keep the string values.

```
hours = float(input("Enter the number of hours worked in a week:"))
dep = float(input("Enter the number of dependents you have:"))

rate = 16.68
ovrate = 25.02


if hours<=40:
  gross2 = hours * rate
else:
  gross2 = 40*rate + (hours-40)*ovrate
print("Gross pay: ${:.2f}".format(gross2))

ss = gross2*.06
print("Social Security tax: ${:.2f}".format(ss))

federal = gross2*0.14
print("Federal income tax: ${:.2f}".format(federal))

state = gross2*0.5
print("State income tax: ${:.2f}".format(state))

union=10
print("Union dues: $10.00")

if dep>=3:
  family = 35
  print("Family health insurance: $35.00 (additional insurance premiums for your family)")
else:
  family = 0

netDed = ss+federal+state+union+family
print("Total deductions: ${:.2f}".format(netDed))

netPay = gross2-netDed
print("Net pay: $",netPay)
```

Output:

```
C:\tmp>python x.py
Enter the number of hours worked in a week:123
Enter the number of dependents you have:34
Gross pay: $2743.86
Social Security tax: $164.63
Federal income tax: $384.14
State income tax: $1371.93
Union dues: $10.00
Family health insurance: $35.00 (additional insurance premiums for your family)
Total deductions: $1965.70
Net pay: $ 778.1579999999999
```

Comment: Doing this gave me the following error message: TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Comment: Perhaps you didn't cut-and-paste properly.  That code works fine for me.